# Check URL and mail to webadmin Bash Script

Tags: bash, email

Here is my code which will hit URL and check URL is working or not and will mail to respective webadmins

```
    #!/bin/bash
    curl -s --head http://myurl | head -n 1 |  grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23].." > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
     url1="myurl2 is working fine"
    else
     url1="myurl2 is not working"
    fi

curl -s --head http://myurl2 | head -n 1 |  grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23].." > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
     url2="myurl is working fine"
    else
     url2="myurl is not working"
    fi


    exec 1<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/25
    a=$(cat <<"MAILEND"
    HELO local.domain.name
    MAIL FROM: <send@mydomain.com>
    RCPT TO: <recieve@mail2.com>
    DATA
    From: send@mydomain.com
    To: recieve@mail2.com
    Subject: test
    $url1  $url2.
    .
    QUIT
    .
    MAILEND
    )
    IFS='
    '
    declare -a b=($a)
    for x in "${b[@]}"
     do
       echo $x
       sleep 1
     done
```

How ever in Mail I am getting `$url1 $url2`

This must be due to `$url1 & $url2` is not getting substituted in line `$a`

Can Someone please help

let me mention one thing "mail" or "sendmail" mails get spamed in my domain so sending mails with above method only works fine

I am expecting "myurl is working"  "  myurl2 is not working"

as myurl2 httpd service I have already stopped

Thanks

Comment: Diagnosing the spam problem would seem like a more sustainable solution than reimplementing Sendmail as a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
cat <<"MAILEND"
```

with

```
cat <<MAILEND
```

Putting quotes around the identifier to a "here document" signals to the shell **not** to expand any variables.  This is explained in the "Here Documents" section of `man bash`

Comment: Perfect.. Even I replaced cat with echo without mailend it even work that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is intended as an aside, but since comments don't support code formatting, posting this refactoring here.

```
( cat <<____HERE
From: send@mydomain.com
To: recieve@mail2.com
Subject: test

____HERE

  while read label url; do
    if curl -s --head "$url" | head -n 1 |  grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23].." > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$label is working fine"
    else
        echo "$label is broken"
    fi
done <<____HERE |
    myurl   http://myurl2
    myurl2  http://myurl
____HERE
) | sendmail -oi -t
```

I am assuming that the labels cross-matching each other's URLs is unintentional and/or incidental and/or beyond my limited comprehension.

Comment: curl should be with $label

Comment: No, it should be `"$url"`; but thanks for catching that.

Comment: 1Up for your solution.. I will try to work with this too

Comment: As a further development, it would be useful if the Subject was different in case of failure, which would call for a different refactoring. But this also depends on how you are reading (or otherwise processing) the generated messages.